# Adding a specific entry from one LinkedHashMap to another

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 LinkedHashMaps,

```
LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color> map;
LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color> totalMap;
```

Both are the same but map has had entries deleted from it, through the use of an undo button. In order to redo the previously undone ArrayList, I have been trying to iterate through totalMap, and add every entry up to map.size, as this will replace the points in map with duplicates, and also add one more, how would I go about doing this?

EDIT:
I've been rewriting this several times but this is the latest version I've come out with

```
public LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color> putNext(LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color> map1,
                                                      LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color> map2) {
    for (Map.Entry<ArrayList<Point>, Color> entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        if (map1.size() < map2.size()) {
            map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return map1;
}
```

EDIT2:

I am writing a paint program that rotates/reflects all points to produce a pattern, [Seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8E8N.png)

To draw the points I have been creating an ArrayList which will then draw to the screen in the paintComponent() method. In order to deal with small changes, such as the number of sectors, and undo/redo, I have been adding the ArrayList to a LinkedHashMap, before nullifying it. When dealing with Undo, I have made two Maps, map and totalMap which are the same, but when undo() is called, it removes the latest entry from map, while totalMap remains untouched.

What I have been trying to do is, when redo is pressed, it will get the entry from totalMap, at index map.size, and put it in map.

Thanks

Comment: *I have been trying*: so, where is the code you tried? Why not just use putAll()? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-?

Comment: I think some more explanation is required. You should never use ArrayLists as map keys.

Comment: When I first thought about how to do this I thought it'd be impractical to do it this way but I couldn't think of another

Comment: @JBNizet For each time Redo is pressed it should only add the next entry from totalMap, not all of them

Comment: OK. Now, what is the problem with the code you posted? Does it compile? Have you tested it? Does it do what you want? What do you expect from us?

Comment: @JBNizet it all compiles successfully but when pressing redo, all of the entries are added, rather than just one more entry

Comment: Are you *misusing* a `LinkedHashMap` as a `List` of paired values? Where an action appends a `ArrayList<Point>, Color` pair to the end, undo removes the last entry, and redo re-adds it from the other map? If so, create a class for the pair of values, and replace the `Map` with a `List` of that class.

Comment: It does sound to me like you shouldn't be using a map, based on your short description of what you're actually doing. You should have something like a `class UserAction { points; color; }` and keep a list of them. Also see http://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: The declaration `LinkedHashMap<ArrayList<Point>, Color>` is extreme code smell.  Using a mutable object (the `ArrayList<>`) as the key of a map is a recipe for total disaster.  Any change to one of the `ArrayList` objects invalidates the entire map and leads to undefined behavior.  I think this is most defintely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @JimGarrison Yeah I wasn't sure if this was the best way to go about it, but I do not need to change any of the ArrayList objects, as I don't need to edit any of the points drawn, only remove/add the ArrayList from/to my BufferedImage

Answer (score 1):

To implement undo/redo logic, you need two stacks, and a class representing the action to be undone/redone.

In your case, it seems an action consists of an `ArrayList<Point>` and a `Color`, so create a class with those as fields.

In a more advanced system, where there can be different types of actions, `Action` would more likely be an `interface`, not a `class`.

You will then have two stacks of action objects. In Java, use a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) when you want stack functionality.

You will then have logic like this:

```
Deque<Action> undoStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
Deque<Action> redoStack = new ArrayDeque<>();

public void doAction(Action action) {
    redoStack.clear(); // new action prevents redo of previous undo
    undoStack.push(action);
}

public Action undoAction() {
    Action action = undoStack.pop(); // Throws exception if stack is empty
    redoStack.push(action);
    return action;
}

public Action redoAction() {
    Action action = redoStack.pop(); // Throws exception if stack is empty
    undoStack.push(action);
    return action;
}
```